# websocket with proxy is not working

Tags: c++, websocket, openssl

I am trying to implement `websocket` client in C++ using `poco` library.

As per my understanding first it is creating socket connection to destination server and send http request and upgrade connection to websocket.

In poco library, `Poco::Net:::HTTPClientSession` has methods:

```
setProxy
setProxyCredentials
setProxyHost
setProxyPort
```

etc.

I used these methods to penetrate the proxy, with respect to client console it show that it has connected and send the request to server while at server console nothing received. when i captured packet trace from client side i observed connection established with proxy server instead of destination server.

Sample code available at Git hub project https://github.com/hannon235/socket.io-poco/tree/master/socket.io-poco

squad (Clear OS) Proxy in use.

I read in forum either proxy setting needs to change or openssl/https need to use.
when i tried with secure connection , packet trace show connection established with destination server but messages are not reach to server.I am not sure how secure connection message send to server.

I want to know how websocket work in secure connection with proxy.

Sample code as below.

```
int main()
{
    //create a c++ Poco logger to use and set its channel to the windows console
    //this is the same logger instance that the library will hook into
    Logger *logger = &(Logger::get("SIOClientLog"));
    logger->setChannel(new WindowsConsoleChannel());

    //Establish the socket.io connection
    //JS: var socket = io.connect("localhost:3000")
    //SIOClient *sio = SIOClient::connect("https://myserver:8004"); this also not working
    SIOClient *sio = SIOClient::connect("http://myserver:8004");

    //Create a target and register object its method onUpdate for the Update event
    TestTarget *target = new TestTarget();
    sio->on("Update", target, callback(&TestTarget::onUpdate));

    //setup is now complete, messages and events can be send and received
    logger->information("sio setup complete\n");

    logger->information("emitting test event\n");

    sio->emit("hello", "[{\"name\":\"myname\",\"type\":\"mytype\"}]");

    //wait for user input to move to next section of code
    //socket receiving occurs in another thread and will not be halted
    logger->information("Press ENTER to continue...");
    std::cin.get();

    //disconnecting the default socket with no endpoint will also disconnect all endpoints
    sio->disconnect();

    logger->information("Press ENTER to quit...");
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Modified Handshake function as below:

```
bool SIOClientImpl::handshake() {
    UInt16 aport = _port;

    _session = new HTTPClientSession(_host, aport);
    _session->setProxy("192.168.60.2",8080);
    _session->setProxyCredentials("user1","user1");
    _session->setKeepAlive(TRUE);

    HTTPRequest req(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET,"/socket.io/1",HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
    req.setKeepAlive(TRUE);

    HTTPResponse res;

    try {
        _session->sendRequest(req);
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        return false;
    }

    std::istream& rs = _session->receiveResponse(res);
    std::cout << res.getStatus() << " " << res.getReason() << std::endl;

    ....
}
```

Comment: No response last 6 days :(